# I want to show an loading image with text underneath in a jquery thick box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am opening an iframe in a jquery thickbox . I want to show an loading image with some some text underneath when the iframe gets loaded. I did every login but my problem is how i can create my css in such a way that the loading image and underneath text is at the center of the jquery thickbox in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this--

```
<div  id="submitPage">
  <img src="loading.gif" alt="">
  Your text...
</div>

#submitPage {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 746px;
  height: 201px;
  background: #0ff; 
  z-index: 99;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 90px;
  margin-left: -373px;
  line-height: 201px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f00;
}
#submitPage img{
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: none;
}
```